# Discord.py bot mentioning a random user

Tags: python, discord.py

trying to make a discord bot that mentions random users on discord.py using the members list but each time I try it says that members is not defined, im not sure if i am misunderstanding what members is but help would be appreciated. :)

1.name = []

2.for member in members:

3. name.append(member)
4. print(member)

Answer (score 1):

you need to import random

```py
#list name
name = []
#for loop get all members in guild
for member in ctx,guild,members:
        #going to append to list name
        name.append(member)
#sned the random member
await ctx.send(random.choice(name))
```

the output

```py
coolman#1890
```

good luck :)